# HTTP 404 "Page not found" error while flagging

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, 404-not-found

I get an HTTP 404 "[Page not found](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6260813/vote/6?close-main=4&close-offtopic=%3C%25=%20reason.id%20%25%3E&fkey=6a3e0ae35e748d2bb1b47deb6086fa22&isForFlagging=true)" error while flagging a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260813/validate-review-system-in-magento) (the link is for 10k users) on Stack Overflow.

Reproducible by clicking the following sequence:

1. flag (1st time)
2. select "it doesn't belong here"
3. click on "back"
4. click on "cancel"
5. flag (2nd time)
6. select "it doesn't belong here"
7. select "not a real question"
8. flag question and you get "Page not found"

I don't know though, whether it's only a problem with this particular question, or if it's a more general problem.

Comment: I can reproduce this bug myself.

Comment: I can also reproduce this bug.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't get the error because the question was already deleted?

Comment: @kiamlaluno: this question posted june 7th, SO question deleted june 9th

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All sorted; an edge condition in the javascript / page when loading the dialog multiple times - entirely our fault. It should work fine after the next build.