# 404 error during flagging a question

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, error-message, 404-not-found

This is maybe a duplicate like [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94112/http-404-page-not-found-error-while-flagging), but the error still appears.

When I try to click "mark as duplicate" a HTTP 404 error occur.

I'm using Firefox 16.0.2 with Firebug on Mac OS X 10.5.8

[image]

Comment: I am having the same problem. I am currently the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: It now works for me, for some reason.

Comment: The same is happening for me - Chrome Version 28.0.1500.71.  The request for the '/close/popup' page returns with a 404 error

Comment: Adding a comment because cannot upvote yet. I get this error too (chrome). Unlike the linked question, this happens for me the first time I try to flag, not after a cancel. The other flag reasons are not affected for me, just duplicate/does not belong here.

Comment: Looks like the problem is still there, it also happened to me (with Firefox) while I was trying to flag a question as duplicate

Comment: Hmm I tried it now again, and it doesn't worked. Now in google chrome 21.0.1180.90

Comment: I'm having the same problem in both Chrome 28.0.1500.95 and Safari 6.0.5 (8536.30.1).

Comment: So I tested it now from another location. As the error occurred I was in the north of germany. Today I'm near Frankfurt (Big internet junction) and the error doesn't occurred. But I don't have a answer on that.

Comment: Having the same problem today