# Getting 404 when closing a deleted question

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, deleted-questions

I flagged [a spam post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18054223/nhp-khu-phan-phi-va-cung-cp-cac-thit-b-phong-chay-cha-chay-thit-b-con). I also wanted to close-vote. But the post was deleted in the meantime by Community♦.

Always when hitting the *close* button I got a 404 error message:

[image: 404 error]

Comment: Yes, the error message should be more descriptive, to let you understand what happened. In the specific case, it doesn't make sense to vote to close the question since it was spam; in such a case, you flag it as spam and wait it gets deleted. The same situation could happen when somebody ask a legitim question that needs to be closed, and you vote to close it right after the OP deleted it, though. In this case, it is worth fixing the error message.

Comment: Probably duplicate: [404 error during flagging a question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187255/187824).

Comment: @kiamlaluno: It is always worth fixing error messages.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I would always still vote to close after flagging spam; the _delete_ option could become available prior to a moderator intervening (not to mention early removal of the potential for that _there-is-always-one-who-will-answer_ answer), hence a quicker turnaround is declining visibility.

Comment: @GrantThomas It is pretty useless to vote to close a spam question, since in most of the cases it gets deleted before getting closed.  Answering a spam question doesn't make any harm; it bumps the question on the front page, if all, and that just has the effect of making it more visible to get flagged as spam.

Comment: Six spam flags and a post is automatically deleted. So it seems unlikely that the question will get closed (5 votes) and then deleted (3 votes) *before* it gets automatically removed as spam. @grant

Comment: All that aside - we get an ugly error when trying to close a deleted post :)