# Getting "404" when selecting "close" on deleted question

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, deleted-questions, 404-not-found

It looks like [Getting 404 when closing a deleted question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191948/157730) has resurfaced.

I don't have any screenshots, but the general steps to reproduce would appear to be:

1. Open a question.
2. Have someone else delete said question (or do it yourself from another session).
3. Click "close" below the question.

At this point, you get a red "404" error box, as shown in this screenshot borrowed from the above-linked question:

[image: 404 error]

The chain of duplicates on the above-linked question ends at [Users without commenting privilege can't select the “it doesn't belong here” flag reason; a “404” error box appears when they try](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192003/157730), which is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). However, the fact that I got this same error about two months later would seem to indicate either a larger issue, that the questions indeed were not duplicates, or a regression.

Either way, I believe a developer should take a look at this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed in next release (2013.11.12.1146). Until now we simply returned a 404 error if either the question was not found or the action was not allowed. Now you'll be getting a more descriptive error message when you run into the action not allowed scenario.

[image]

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that "action not allowed" covers "question has been deleted"? If it does, good job for fixing it so quickly :)

Comment: well, if the question is already deleted (or locked) you are not allowed to delete it (again).

Comment: Good point. I'll have to see if someone can help verify this once that release goes live.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling yep, just got "This question is now deleted" when trying to close a deleted (non closed) question. [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dbUwY.png).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Looks great!