# Users without commenting privilege can't select the "it doesn't belong here" flag reason; a "404" error box appears when they try

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, privileges

I attempted to flag [this question on Christianity.SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/18136/please-christian-moderators-help)...

> [image]

...as "off topic". Although the initial flag dialog loads correctly, every time I selected the "it doesn't belong here, or is a duplicate" option, the next pane would fail to load:

> [image]

```
Request URL:https://christianity.stackexchange.com/flags/questions/18136/close/popup?_=1375739403107
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

The account had 46 reputation. I tested this on other sites, but found that it only occurred on Christianity.SE. This was my only account that has the for the [flagging privilege](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) but not enough for the [comment privilege](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

---

I have now earned the commenting privilege on Christianity and am no longer able to reproduce this error, confirming its cause.

Comment: Appears to also reproduce with the [duplicate close reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187255/404-error-during-flagging-a-question), which also attempts to create a comment without the privilege.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a `412 Precondition Failed` or `410 Conflict` instead?

Comment: @ColeJohnson It should be a `200 OK`. ;)

Comment: @JeremyBanks why not [`418 I'm a teapot`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185426/stack-overflow-returning-http-error-code-418-im-a-teapot)?

Comment: Holy Unintended Consequence, Batman!  Yeah, close shouldn't be blocked by inability to comment; the close should just go through without posting the comment.

Answer (score 4):

Jarrod fixed this - if a flag type requires commenting privileges (as off-topic flags do) and the user doesn't have them, that flag type will not come up.

This is currently live.

Comment: Fair enough, though it appears some people don't really like that solution.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I can see where they may be coming from. Doesn't mean this is a permanent situation.

Comment: In my opinion it's not a big deal, 15-50 is quite an edge case but still, it feels like more a hack than real solution. Still, better than a 404 error. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - not disagreeing with you...

Comment: @Oded I got the same error just now when clicking "close" on a question that was deleted in the interim. Red box 404 with the X to close. Maybe it's the same error and maybe it's unrelated, but seems worth looking at again. I'd expect it to be pretty easy to reproduce.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - do you mind opening a new Meta bug with a repro?

Comment: @Oded http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/207005/157730