# Unable to flag my own question [can't delete as already answered]

Tags: support

If I try to flag my own question it pops up a 404 error message. Even I can't delete my question(it carries downvotes) as it has already been answered.

Please give me a solution how to remove the question.

Comment: Deleting your question is a bad idea. It will make it harder to get out of your question ban. Please read the message that comes up when you try to post a question.

Comment: People put their time and effort in answering your question, why should their answers be deleted?

Comment: I just want to get rid of the downvotes cast on my question. Can you propose a way out???

Comment: @RajeshPaul Improve the question.

Comment: @Yannis: Thanx. Done with that, but still I think the question is silly from my present point of view.

Comment: Silly as in basic? Basic questions are valuable too. Especially if they're well written

Comment: And by the way what is the reason behind the 404 error?

Comment: @RichardTingle: valuable advice...

Comment: @RajeshPaul its a bug... already been reported.  If I remember the explanation correctly, it is coming up because you don't have enough privleges to comment

Comment: @psubsee2003: Does that happen even if I want that on my own question?

Comment: @RajeshPaul until you get the 50 rep needed to comment.

Comment: @RajeshPaul [here's the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192003/users-without-commenting-privilege-cant-select-the-it-doesnt-belong-here-fla) to the bug report.

Comment: Posting here was the proper action. Moderator can now delete your question, although personally I don't think it's correct.

Comment: You can always comment on your posts - even with reputation of 1.

Comment: @Oded:Actually I wanted to flag my own question. But it resulted in 404 error. What is the reason?

Comment: Not sure. Sounds like a bug.

Comment: can you link us to the question? might be able to advise a bit more clearly as to why you're getting down votes, and you can improve it and know for the future

Comment: @James: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18718904/is-there-any-significance-of-using-scope-resolution-operator-with-an-object/18719162?noredirect=1#18719162

Comment: I guess the meaning of the question is quite clear and to the point but  it is probably a very basic question and hence got downvoted. I think there is hardly any scope of improving it. Now onwards I shouldn't dare to ask very basic questions but I still hope I'm wrong. My basic question can cause me harm my reputation score. Isn't it???